# Convert UIBezierPath in similar way to CGRect, CGPoint, etc

Tags: swift, uiview, uibezierpath, cgaffinetransform

`UIView` has functions to convert points, rects, etc. between coordinate spaces. I need to do the same thing for `UIBezierPaths`. By way of illustration, consider two views, `viewA` and `viewB`. We have `rectA : CGRect` in the coordinate space of `viewA`. We can calculate:

```
let rectB = viewB.convert(rectA, from:viewA)
```

Now suppose we create a path from the rect:

```
let pathA = UIBezierPath(rect: rectA)
```

The question is, how to calculated `rectB`. We could simply:

```
let pathB = UIBezierPath(rect: rectB)
```

But that works only if we have `rectB`. What if we only have `pathA'?

I figure to do this we need a transform `aTob`. Then we can do:

```
var pathB = pathA
pathB.apply(aTob)
```

So the question boils down to how to calculate `aTob`. For simplicity, assume there is no rotation.

With the result, drawing `pathA` in `viewA` should draw a path in the same shape and location on the screen as drawing `pathB` in `viewB`.

Comment: `UIBezierPath` has an [`apply()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibezierpath/1624340-apply) method that takes a `CGAffineTransform`; does creating a scaling transform (translating from the size of `viewA` to the size of `viewB`) give you the results you expect?

Comment: My question suggests that apply method. The question is how to calculate the transform. In my use case, both views have the same superview but may have different origins and different anchors. I'm surprised there doesn't seem to be a public API to return a transform given two views.

Comment: Ah, sorry! I somehow missed that "apply" and "transform" were referring to this specific approach.

Comment: What I wound up doing was to convert the bounds of `viewB` to `viewA` coordinates, then calculate transform by adjusting scale and then origin for translation. I'll probably write an extension to make it more generic and that can handle rotation as well.

Comment: I think a generic solution might use a recursive function that traverses one view to the other via the common ancestor, concatenating the inverse transform at each step until the common ancestor, then the transforms of the remaining steps. Note that it works only if both views have a common ancestor.

Comment: @VictorEngel What about the answer I posted? Does it not solve your issue?

Comment: No. It does not work. It works only for translations. It is completely wrong if there is any scaling. Anyway, I have a solution that works by tracking the scaling, but I may work on this solution again if I get some free time.

Comment: @VictorEngel Your question doesn't say anything about scaling. But's that trivial to add. Please update your question to clarify the requirements and I'll update my answer to adjust for scaling. Also, in the future, if someone posts an answer to your question, please respond to let them know if it meets the needs or not. This will make it easier to get the desired answer. Simply ignoring an answer does not help anyone. Something to consider.

Comment: Not needed. I said there was no rotation. That implies anything else is applicable. By assuming there is no scaling, you have turned the question into something it isn't. The question is clear.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to call [`apply()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibezierpath) on the bezier path using a translation transform.

You can calculate the needed x and y of the transform by converting the origin of `viewB` to the coordinate space of `viewA`.

Here's is some sample code you can put in a Swift Playground:

```swift
// Some setup
let rectA = CGRect(x: 40, y: 60, width: 200, height: 100)
let rectB = CGRect(x: 10, y: 80, width: 200, height: 100)
let viewA = UIView(frame: rectA)
let viewB = UIView(frame: rectB)
// Create pathA
let pathA = UIBezierPath(rect: rectA)

// Calculate the offset needed to move from viewA to viewB
let offset = viewA.convert(CGPoint.zero, from: viewB)
let tranform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: offset.x, y: offset.y)
// Copy pathA
let pathB = UIBezierPath()
pathB.append(pathA)
// Shift pathB
pathB.apply(tranform)
// Check result
print(pathA)
print(pathB)
```

Output:

```
<UIBezierPath: 0x600002c31e80; <MoveTo {40, 60}>,
 <LineTo {140, 60}>,
 <LineTo {140, 160}>,
 <LineTo {40, 160}>,
 <Close>
<UIBezierPath: 0x600002c12280; <MoveTo {10, 80}>,
 <LineTo {110, 80}>,
 <LineTo {110, 180}>,
 <LineTo {10, 180}>,
 <Close>
```

I believe this is what you are looking for. The calculation of `offset` might be backwards. If the result of `pathB` is in the wrong direction, change the `offset` line to:

```swift
let offset = viewB.convert(CGPoint.zero, from: viewA)
```

Here's an extension to `UIView` for converting a `UIBezierPath` from one view to/from another:

```swift
extension UIView {
    private func adjust(_ path: UIBezierPath, by offset: CGPoint) -> UIBezierPath {
        let transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: offset.x, y: offset.y)
        let result = UIBezierPath()
        result.append(path)
        result.apply(tranform)

        return result
    }

    func convert(_ path: UIBezierPath, from view: UIView) -> UIBezierPath {
        let offset = convert(CGPoint.zero, from: view)

        return adjust(path, by: offset)
    }

    func convert(_ path: UIBezierPath, to view: UIView) -> UIBezierPath {
        let offset = convert(CGPoint.zero, to: view)

        return adjust(path, by: offset)
    }
}
```

This answer assumes that neither view has a non-identity transform applied to it. Based on the OP's own answer, apparently one or both of the views may have a non-identity transform.

Answer (score 0):

Using an extension like the one HangarRash posted, here is a solution that works when both views have the same superview.

```
func convert(_ path: UIBezierPath, from view: UIView) -> UIBezierPath {
    path.apply(view.transform)
    // we now have a path in view's superview's coordinates. Let's adjust by the origin.
    let viewTransform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: view.frame.origin.x, y: view.frame.origin.y)
    path.apply(viewTransform)
    
    // now the path is adjusted by view's origin. Next we need to subtract self's origin
    let selfTranslationTransform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: -self.frame.origin.x, y: -self.frame.origin.y)
    path.apply(selfTranslationTransform)
    
    // now adjust by self's transform
    path.apply(self.transform.inverted())
    return path
}
```

Comment: How does this scale the bezier path? All you end up doing here is translate which you claimed didn't answer your question. I'm confused now.

Comment: path.apply(view.transform) applies any scale on the view in the argument. And, path.apply(self.transform.inverted()) applies an inverted transform of self, which could also have a scale. This was tested with views randomly positioned with random scaling factors. It fails if there is a rotation.

Comment: I realize now I misread your answer. The first and last (inverted) transforms are from the two different views. I made my first comment thinking they were from the same view. So my current answer works if neither view has a non-identity transform. Your question isn't as clear as it could be. You make no mention of the views having transforms applied to them. You only talked about view rects and adjusting the bezier path between the two rects.

Comment: I mentioned different coordinate spaces. The two rects I mentioned have different coordinate spaces. I stated that outright. What determines a coordinate space? The location of the origin and a transform. Transforms can be modified or initialized by translation, scale, and rotation. I said for simplicity assume no rotation. That leaves the other two. It couldn't be more clear.

Comment: Yes, it's perfectly clear after further commentary. As the author, you knew exactly what your question meant. As a reader, not all of those details are as clear. Glad you solved your issue.